# Image map on home page responsive center

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, responsive

I've been reading this forum for a while now and decided that I might find help on this one because I couldn't find any exact answer.

I want to make a landing page with a big photo and put a responsive image map on it. I can make a map, I can put an image but the problems start when I want to make it responsive while the image stays centered (background-position: center). If I don't use the background-position:center the image is looking really small on mobile and it won't work like this.

I know that I can try putting a transparent image on the background but I don't know how to make the map responsive then.

Here is the link to my work site if you can help me http://www.mafia.brandscatter.com/

Comment: Hi Tomas, please take a tour of the help centre and see how to ask a good question.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj0w9dnf/1/

```
.background{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  padding:25%;
}

.map{
  background-color:blue;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}


<div class="background">
  <div class="map">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work as I wanted, I decided to pay someone to do it and will provide a solution here when I will have it.